# How to get the same class variable of a list of class instances of the same class?

Tags: python

I have a class which has some class variables, methods, etc. Let's call it `Cell`.

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self):
        self.status = 0
        ...
```

I have a list of different instances of this class.

```
grid = [Cell.Cell() for i in range(x_size*y_size)]
```

Is it possible to get the upper shown `status` variable of each of the instances stored in `grid` in a vectorized manner without looping through the elements of the list?

Comment: No, not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in vanilla Python.

```
statuses = [x.status for x in grid]
```

If you are looking for something that abstracts away the explicit iteration, or even just the `for` keyword, perhaps you'd prefer

```
from operator import attrgetter

statuses = list(map(attrgetter('status'), grid))
```

?

Comment: The latter isn't any more vectorized than the list comprehension; the iteration is simply done by `map` "out of sight".

Comment: Yeah, I see. I was actually looking for a solution using maps because usually, I parallelize maps with the multiprocessing's Pool. It can be used here too right? Or in this case, it won't be much more efficient?

Comment: If all you're doing is fetching an attribute and sticking it in a list, I wouldn't expect parallelizing it to make it any more efficient (in fact I'd expect the opposite).

Comment: OK, understood! Thank you! I'll just stick to the latter solution as it seems cleaner for me.